# Creating Virtual Network Azure - The Gateway was not created

Tags: azure, networking

It's been sitting at "THE GATEWAY WAS NOT CREATED." for hours after creating a Virtual Network in Azure. Is this normal? What should I do?

We previously created a network in the wrong DC, it didn't seem to be so slow then.

Comment: Stupid me. Missed the "Create Gateway" button at the bottom. Blah

I think the UI should be clearer.

Comment: You saved me some time Timmah!

Comment: Haha, same here! I hate the "classic" portal. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to click the create gateway button. :)

Here are the steps to create the site to site VPN.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/10/09/step-by-step-create-a-site-to-site-vpn-between-your-network-and-azure.aspx

Also this can be done manually:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/igorpag/archive/2013/08/27/manually-adding-a-vpn-gateway-to-azure-virtual-network.aspx